# Connect JUCE to a WebRTC or audio streaming server

Tags: c++, webrtc, audio-streaming, juce

I am working on a project, the project is about building a VST plugin that can connect to a realtime audio streaming server and it will receive and send audio in realtime, and I am considering building the VST plugin using JUCE as it is one of the best for a project like this, but I have been looking for JUCE class for achieving something like that and the only similar class I found is the `StreamingSocket` class, though I haven't checked it out but looking at the `StreamingSocket` class documentation it looks like it is just for connecting to a (web) socket server that can be used to build something like realtime user chat.

and please note: I am new to C++

My main questions are:

1. Is there a JUCE class or library for connecting to an audio streaming server / WebRTC server, and that can send and receive audio in realtime?
2. Is there another C++ open source framework like JUCE that I can use to build a VST plugin that can send and receive audio in real time?
3. Because I love python than C++, is there a python library/framework like JUCE that can be used to build VST plugins.
4. Is it even possible to connect a C++ application to an audio/video streaming server / simply WebRTC server?
5. is there any C++ library for connecting to audio streaming server / WebRTC server, that can connect to, receive and send audio to an audio streaming server / WebRTC server?

thank you for your help in advance :)